# How would you go about refreshing your application once you have pressed any key? C#

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I'm currently creating a program; I cannot figure out how to refresh the application after a key is pressed.

So far I have:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key To Refresh");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Full Code Block

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        int userInput;
        DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows");
        FileInfo[] files = folderInfo.GetFiles();


        Console.WriteLine("Welcome To File Manager");

        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine("Current Folder: C:\\Windows");

        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine("Please Select An Opion Between 1 To 4:"); // Displays Options for Main Menu. 
        Console.WriteLine("1. ");
        Console.WriteLine("2. ");
        Console.WriteLine("3. ");
        Console.WriteLine("4. ");
        userInput =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        { 
            if (userInput == 1)   
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Files in C:\\Windows:");
                for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++) // Lists The Files Within The Speficied Folder C:\\Windows - Also Assigns Numerical Value To Each File. 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}" , index + ". " + 1 + files[index].Name + "   (" +(files[index].Length) + ")"); 


                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key To Return To Main Menu");
                Console.ReadKey();



            }

            else if (userInput == 2)
            {
                // code for option 2 
            }
            else if (userInput == 3)
            {
                // Code for option 3
            }
            else if (userInput == 4)
            {
               // Closes Application.
            }
        } while (userInput != 4);
```

Once the operation within option (1) has ran, the message; "Press Any Key To Refresh" appears - Afterwards I'd like it to refresh the application once a key is pressed!

I hope this clarifies what I was asking!

Many Thanks
- Dan

Comment: What does it mean to "refresh" your C# application?

Comment: The application restards itself without closing/reopening - is that possible?

Comment: I am guessing this is for some intro to programming class. Wrap the whole thing in a `while(refresh) loop` loop and define refresh as a boolean outside the loop and initialize to `true`. Only set refresh to `false` if the user processes some specific key at the bottom of your `while` block where you have the 2 lines above defined.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score -1):

This may help if I understood correctly what you want to accomplish.

```
        bool isClicked = true;

        while(isClicked)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Select An Opion Between 1 To 4:");
            int userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (userInput)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key To Return To Main Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();

                    //isClicked = false;        // Used to suspend the operation

                    break;
                case 2:
                    // code for option 2 
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // code for option 3
                    break;
                case 4:
                    // code for option 4 
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Error occured");
                    break;
            }
        }
```